# SQL Alchemy relationship with `where` clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to make a relationship like such:

```
class Games(Base):
    publishers = relationship(GameCompany).where(GameCompany.role == 'publisher')
    developers = relationship(GameCompany).where(GameCompany.role == 'developer')
```

Essentially, create a model attribute which does a join and and has a where clause.

```
GameCompany(game_id, company_id, role)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. Please read [Specifying Alternate Join Conditions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) section of `sqlalchemy` documentation with a sample code. The code for your model will probably look like this:

```
class GameCompany(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('games.id'))
    # ...

class Games(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    publishers = relationship(GameCompany, 
        primaryjoin=and_(GameCompany.game_id == id, GameCompany.role == 'publisher'))
    developers = relationship(GameCompany, 
        primaryjoin=and_(GameCompany.game_id == id, GameCompany.role == 'developer'))
```